# How can I apply read only attribute to all .docx and .pptx files in the C: directory? Using java

Tags: java

Please I am trying to apply setReadOnly() function to all documents having the .docx and .pptx file extension in my C: drive. As in the readonly show apply to any document that has the file extension in C: directory. 
Please someone show assist me on how to implement that. This is what I have able to come with but I don’t think is the correct way nor the correct code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileReadAttribute {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     File file = new File("C:*.docx");
     file.setReadOnly();

     if(file.canWrite()) {
         System.out.println("This file is writable");
     } else {
         System.out.println("This file is read only");
     }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileReadAttribute {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     File c_drive = new File("C:\\");
     setPermission(c_drive);

 }

private static void setPermission(File parent) {
        File[] files = parent.listFiles();//get all files of this directory
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                setPermission(file); //set permission of the files in this directory
            } else {
                String fileExtension = getFileExtension(file);
                if (fileExtension.equals("docx") || fileExtension.equals("pptx")) {
                    file.setReadOnly();
                }
            }
        }

    }

private static String getFileExtension(File file) {
    String name = file.getName();
    return name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
}

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "the code don't actually point to the directory"?

Comment: @ Jakob Herk I am trying to target C drive. from your code I cant see the drive indicated

Comment: then you can pass any file object like new File("C:/") when calling the method. This is a recursion, so the method is calling itself till a certain condition returns false. So all you have to do is calling: setPermission(new File("C:"));

Comment: @ Jakob Herk I am new to java, don't really get it. can u just fixed it for me in the previous code u comment?

Comment: i changed it. Have a look at it

Comment: You could explain your answer, so that people can actually learn from it rather than just copying and pasting code they don't understand.

Comment: @ Jakob Herk  how about to apply the search to  sub directories as well. I notice it only apply to the parent directory i.e C: and doesnt apply to all the sub directories of C

Comment: @Jakob Herk never mind i have solve it. it was just to put a slash to the drive.  File c_drive = new File("C:\\");

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FileNameFilter`. This should work

```
    File dir = new File("/users/blah/dirname");
    File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".docx");
        }
    });

    if (files != null) {
        Stream.of(files).forEach(File::setReadOnly);
    }
```

If you are using Java less than 8. Replace `Stream.of` with traditional for loop.